# When and why should i use 403 error code?

Tags: rest, error-handling, error-code

In my application i have a case in which i have feature which will be enabled in enterprise and standard edition. In this feature, I have count limit for creation of an entity. The count limit is same for both the editions. Should i throw 403 when the count is exceeded ? or just return 422 error code?
Thanks

Comment: You can use 402  - payment required

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should return http status 406. Not Acceptable. As this is the current status of the server.

403 status is suitable for when the user is logged but does not have enough requirements for do the action in server.

Along with error 406 you should put a msg for pay or increase the current account limits.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. But the count limit cant be increased based on the pay as of now. But i can be moved unser payable entity.

Comment: In that case I recommend using the status code 412 Pré-conditions failed as the user got  his limits.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to recognize is that the status code of the response, is (like header values) *metadata*: it is information provided in a standardized form so that general-purpose components can understand the semantics of what is going on.  Fine grained details belong in the message body.

Consider, for instance, the model of the web: if we want browsers/caches/reverse-proxies/web-spiders to understand what is going on, we use meta data.  For the *human* readers of the web, the fine grain details are provided in the response payload.

Also, the metadata belongs to the [transporting documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain; the server is doing interesting things behind the facade that looks like a website.

Because status codes are intended for general purpose components, our primary measure for the correctness of an error code is "will a general purpose component do the right thing?" when it sees it.

[403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) has this meaning in HTTP/1.1:

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

The word "authorize" sometimes trips people up, because it sounds like this status is specific to credentials.  A more careful reading indicates otherwise

> a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.

In [HTTP/1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-9.4), the language was slightly different

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

`403` means "I'm not going to allow *you* to do it", but is ambiguous about whether somebody else might be allowed to do it.

The other possibility you might consider is [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8).

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.

As far as I can tell, these codes are equivalent, in the sense that general purpose components will behave in similar ways to each.

I don't consider [406 Not Acceptable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6), because this is a question about domain logic, and 406 is about [proactive negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.1).  Similarly, I don't consider [412 Precondition Failed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) for failures that are unrelated to [precondition headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3).

Again, the theme here is that we are looking for the right match in the HTTP domain.